# Error: pip installed django but 'django-admin' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I am trying to create a file using `django-admin startproject sample_project` on my command line. I used pip to install Django but for some reason, I keep getting this error:

`'django-admin' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Django has been installed (I can see the version on the command) but I am specifically having an issue with django-admin.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-and-manage-py

Comment: I have tried setting up a path to the site-packages directory that contains Django but it still is not working